# I'm attempting to make a placeholder image for my app in react when theres no image available

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm developing a movie browser application in reactjs using moviedb's api to return Json files with movies and their corresponding posters. Some film return a poster path of null as there is no poster available so I tried to write a conditional statement to use a placeholder instead but it doesn't seem to affect the poster_src.I place the films into an array and display each film through a loop.

When I query for a film the poster is return as poster_src but since some films don't have poster it returns https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185null with no image so I attempted to check if poster_src was equal to the string and then change it to the placeholder if it was true.

My query to return and place the list of films into an array.

```
$.ajax({
    url: urlString,
    success: (searchResults) => {
        console.log("Fetched data")
        const results = searchResults.results
        console.log(searchResults)

        var movieRows = []
```

My conditional statement to see if the poster is equal to a dead link and if so change it to a placeholder image.

```
if (movie.poster_src === "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185null")
{
    movie.poster_src = "https://critics.io/img/movies/poster-placeholder.png";
}
return poster_src;
```

I'm just hoping to simply change the poster_src according to the contents returned and then hopefully replace the image with a default placeholder. Anything i looked at online didn't seem to fix my issue so I was wondering if anybody might see the issue as it is probably something very minor.

Comment: does `searchResults.results` return null or `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185null` ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop through your data set to change the image `src`. Instead, you can use conditional rendering to display the correct image.

Make the call:

```
let _this = this;
$.ajax({
  url: urlString,
  success: (searchResults) => {
      console.log("Fetched data")
      _this.setState({
        movieRows: searchResults.results
      })
   }
})
```

Then render the view

```
render() {
  var movies = this.state.movieRows.map(x => {
    let img = x.poster_src == "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185null" ? "https://critics.io/img/movies/poster-placeholder.png" : x.poster_src
    return (
      <div>
        <img src={img} />
      </div>
    )
  })
  return (<div>{movies}</div>)
}
```

Comment: Or just use x.poster_{ src !== "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185null"  ?   <img src={x.poster_src} />  :  <img src="https://critics.io/img/movies/poster-placeholder.png" /> } its a bit more concise